# show highcharts node description only in mouse over

Tags: highcharts

Is there any possability to show the description of a Node only when mouse over is active? In my exampel both the name and the dexcription of the node will be shown in the node an in the mouse over box.

I want to show the "Merkmale | Makro zur Prüfung" in the node and "[MORE.OAI] Office AddIn
(370/454,6)
CR: OfficeAddin/DMS-AddIn für MS-Outlook, MS-Excel und MS-Word [OAI]
(/449,1)" in the mouse over box.

`Code https://jsfiddle.net/omurx8Lk/4/`

Comment: Hi @Bianca M, It seems that there is no easy way to achieve that. You need to for example add `mouseover` event and change CSS style. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6mrd2015/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the example. Is there also a way to change the text on mouseover event? Because I want to show only while the mouseover event a description. I have tried it with this.children[0].description = "test"; But nothing happens.

Comment: You need to go deeper into the HTML tree and change `innerHTML`. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6mrd2015/1/